# How to use bazel to statically link tensorflow C API to libstdc++ and libgcc_s?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, tensorflow, bazel

I wanted to compile tensorflow C API as a shared library for Debian Wheezy and because some of its dependencies use C++11 features not supported in gcc version available in Wheezy, I ended up compiling never gcc and instaling it locally on my machine.

Now if I compile tensorflow with bazel, using my local gcc installation, I end up with a binary that is dynamically linked to `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` that come from the local gcc installation:

```
$ ldd libtensorflow_c.so 
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc06351e000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /my/local/path/gcc-4.9.4-installation/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc0638ab000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /my/local/path/gcc-4.9.4-installation/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc063307000)
    ...
```

I'd like to use the compiled tensorflow library on other machines and so I don't want it to depend on the non-standard location of `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s`. One possibility is to link them statically, but I can't make bazel to do it.

I tried to set the linker flags `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` in bazel's `tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL` file, passed them as `linkopts` to the `cc_binary` target (named `libtensorflow_c.so`) in tensorflow's `BUILD` file (tried setting `linkstatic = 1` there as well) and also used them in `--linkopt` option of `bazel build` command, but the result is that both libraries are still linked dynamically.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "no success"? What kind of error do you get, or does it just work but no static linking is done?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Yep. It works, but no static linking is done. I clarified this in the question as well.

Comment: Maybe using the makefile in tensorflow/contrib/makefile, which might be easier to modify to do what you want?